# Android: slow response after clicking TabWidget

Tags: android

I have 3 tabs inside a page.But it is taking too much time to switch over different tab widgets.What would be the reason and how can i make the process faster ? Any help will be greatly appreciated ...

Comment: it's hard to find out the reason, without knowing that what are doing in those Tabs..

Comment: what you load in tabactivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are doing some stuff that is making your `UI` `freeze`. So, it would be better to use `AsyncTask`/`Service`/`IntentService` any of these depending on your requirement.

Comment: i am using a continuous loop,map view and list view in side thes tabs.

Comment: You should add in your question about what you are doing in the Tabs `onCreate()`.

Comment: ok.In my first tab, i am having a mapview and calling an infinite loop to get the location updates..And in the second tab i have a list view and an infinite loop to get new coming messages, same as third tab..

Comment: I guess you are surely doing some UI updating in infinite loops thats causing your Tabs to work slow.